# How long does a Radiation Storm usually last?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing in Survival Mode.

A Radiation Storm started so I found shelter in a closed building. I've been waiting for **24 ingame hours** now, checking every two ingame hours if the storm has passed, but it still there... and I'm almost out of food and water.

Is it a bug? Can a Radiation Storm possibly last so long?

**EDIT.** More details in case it happens to somedy else: The Rad Storm started when I was around [General Atomics Galeria](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/General_Atomics_Galleria). I found shelter in the [Black Alley Bowling](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Back_Alley_Bowling).

Comment: What did you do to pass the time?  Did you sit in a chair and waited, or just stood there?

Comment: @Nelson, yes, I sat in a chair and waited 2 hours, check the weather outside, came back inside, repeat...

Comment: Short enough you can probably just ignore it, if you have any rad resist (cough, vault suit, cough) at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly enough, according to the [Fallout wikia page on Weather](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Weather), Radstorms typically only last around **2 in-game hours**.

> Radiation storms last for about two in-game hours, and are comparatively rare in terms of weather conditions.

It seems crazy for a radstorm to have lasted 24 in-game hours, though, so it might be that you slept through the end of one radstorm and woke up during another.

Comment: OK, so after waiting 10 hours more, and checking again every two hours, I decided it was a bug and restarted from my previous save. Thanks.

Comment: @Bebs, did that fix it? I've never seen a bug like this...

Comment: Sort of... the previous save (= sleep in Survival) was a little before, so the storm didn't even came back.